# Detect file type in a directory/folder

Tags: java, file

I would like to ask how to know the file/files types in a directory/folder using Java.
The reason for asking is that currently, I have one situation in which there will be 2 different types of files exists in the folder,  which one is java based and another one is python.
I would like to use Java as a language to check whether the type file in the unzipped folder is python(.py) or java(.java) programmatically.  Do you know how to make this work? any suggestion?
There is no possibility to have both types of files in the same folder.  That being said, the file either will be all in java or all in python.

Comment: Have you tried to do this in Java? It is not that hard to look through all the files and find their extensions.

Comment: This can be a start: [Listing files in a directory matching a pattern in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/2102952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can achieved by using the `listFiles` method .

**One way**

```
File [] files = folder.listFiles(f-> f.toString().endsWith(".java"));
```

With python extension

```
File [] files = folder.listFiles(f-> f.toString().endsWith(".py"));
```

Or a better solution creating a method with a parameter so you can after use it every time you need it by just calling it

```
public File [] returnFiles(File folder,String extension){
        
        return folder.listFiles(f-> f.toString().endsWith(extension));
    }
```

**EDIT**

You guaranteed me that the folder will have only the file of Java or Python so when we are listing all the files in our `File [] files` array this array will contain java files or python files so there is no need to check them all we check only one file in this array

Example

```
File[] files = file.listFiles(f -> f.isFile());

        File  fileToCheck;

        if (file.length() >= 0) {
            fileToCheck = files[0];
            int index = fileToCheck.toString().lastIndexOf(".");
            String extension = fileToCheck.toString().substring(index + 1);
            if(extension.equals("java")) {
                System.out.println("Java FrameWork");
            }else if(extension.equals("py")){
                System.out.println("Python FrameWork");
        }

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Typhon, for the really useful information.   In my code,  the folder instead of using File,  we are using a String(folder name basically).  In this case, how to use them if/else or try/catch by using the approach you suggested? Kind regards

Comment: What do you want to check with if conditions?

Comment: something like if there are .java files in the folder, return "java framework",  else if there are .python then return "python framework"

Comment: @Ken check it out.